# Get redirected URL from Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm fetching my images using the following code:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)                              
    .load(myImage.getUrl())
    .fetch();
```

`myImage.getUrl()` returns a URL from my server, which will redirect to the actual image hosted on another server. Is there a way to catch the URL my server returns to Picasso? I know I can use a `Callback` in `.fetch()`, but that's all I know. I'm using OkHttp as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp allows you **not to follow redirects automatically**:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

You can read the response, get the redirect URL and then forward it manually to Picasso.

**EDIT:**

`Interceptor`s are feasible as well:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    // process response here
    return response;
  }
});
```

Comment: I am a little confused. How do I use this with Picasso?

Comment: This is not an answer at all.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by this code.

```
val downloader = OkHttp3Downloader(context)
Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build()
```

Check this for detail.
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463

Answer (score 0):

Add okhttp dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

and try this code

```
  Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
  builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(context));
  builder.build()
 .load(path.trim())
 .into(imageView);
```

This code working for me