# Redirection Image url to use in image view using Picasso - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I have a short url - https://b.xxxxx.com/wzxuum2 which is redirecting to s3 server to get the image. I am already using Picasso in the project. But unfortunately I am not able to use above Url to display the images.

I have tried with -

```
Picasso.with(this)
             .load("https://b.xxxxx.com/wzxuum2")
             .placeholder(R.drawable.qr_temp)
             .into(qr_img)
```

and

```
val builder = Picasso.Builder(this)
        builder.downloader(OkHttpDownloader(this))
        builder.build().load("https://b.xxxxx.com/wzxuum2").into(qr_img)
```

taken reference from here - https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463

but it is not working,
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952860/get-redirected-url-from-picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952860/get-redirected-url-from-picasso)

Answer (score 1):

when i checked your url i saw the redirect goes to the header, so you can take it from there and make a new request. It was possible to check the redirect with `response.isRedirect` but it always returns false, so only works via header check.
[image]

```
val picasso = Picasso.Builder(applicationContext)
                .downloader(OkHttp3Downloader(OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
                    var request = chain.request()
                    val response: Response = chain.proceed(request)
                    val redirectUrl = response.header("Refresh")
                    if (redirectUrl != null) {
                        val url = redirectUrl.substring(redirectUrl.indexOf("url") + 4, redirectUrl.length)
                        request = request.newBuilder()
                                .url(url).build()
                        chain.proceed(request)
                    } else {
                        response
                    }

                }.build()))
                .build()
        picasso.load("https://b.redbus.com/wzxuum2").into(imageView)
```

and we have a result

[image]